# How to set xforcevesa?

Tags: resolution

I have a OQO I'm converting to Natty.

I have a screen resolution problem on the native LCD screen.  I have some indication that xforcevesa will allow the system to get the proper resolution information for my machine.

Where do I put this?  What does the syntax look like?

Comment: What graphics card/chipset do you have?

Answer (score 2):

You can put it into /etc/default/grub. To open the file for editing, run

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

locate the following line and put xforcevesa between the quotes:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="xforcevesa"
```

save and exit when done, then run the following for the change to take effect

```
sudo update-grub
```