# Changing screen resolution on Dell Inspiron

Tags: display

I just installed the latest Ubuntu desktop onto a Dell Inspiron 1000 laptop and I cannot change the screen resolution any higher than VGA using the built-in monitor. any help would be appreciated please.

Comment: What's the model of your graphics card?

Comment: Please [edit] and add output of `lspci | grep VGA`

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with setting the resolution higher on my Dell Inspiron 1000 when I was running Lubuntu. My assumption is that by VGA you mean resolution higher than 640x480.

The fix I found was to set xforcevesa. Now I have 1024x768, 800x600, and 640x480 on Lubuntu 16.04.

If you need help setting xforcevesa see the following.

[How to set xforcevesa?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53279/how-to-set-xforcevesa)

This is what I found in my research that caused me to try xforcevesa.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2162336