# How to restart Ubuntu with startup graphics

Tags: 16.04, graphics, login, dell

How can I get the GUI working again on my messed-up my Ubuntu 16.04, Dell Lattitude 3540?

Currently, the only way to log in is in recovery mode, jumping to the root login terminal.  This started with a foray into the TensorFlow/NVidia package, and has gone downhill from there.  The graphical login screen freezes, entirely, and asking for some status thusly:

```
systemctl status lightdm.service
```

says Active: inactive (dead)

Can I get the system to boot into the generic video driver that seems to run during install and upgrade, so that I can then run Intel's display driver utility?

According to Dell, the machine has AMD Radeon HD 8850M graphics hardware.  I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't know what you did, if i was in your shoes I'd look at the command `history` to see what was done, and reverse it.  If you don't always use commands, packages added can also be found in logs (/var/log/apt/); but in your position I'd look for what you actually did and use that as a plan for reversal.

Comment: @guiverc - Thank you for your thoughtful response.  Unfortunately the changes had been made in 3 different accounts, and I couldn't sort it all out.  -- Bob

Comment: If you have answered it, please don't add the answer to your question text, add the detail in the "Answer" section below these comments.  People can thus upvote your answer (if they like it) plus you can accept it yourself (in time) unless you get a better answer you'd prefer to accept.

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten myself back to a working GUI with the following steps, found in 3 sources: This AskUbuntu answer : [How to set xforcevesa?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53279/how-to-set-xforcevesa) got me out of grub recovery mode, and into a working login screen, with the following edit to /etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="xforcevesa"
```

... but once logged in I still had a blank (but GUI) screen, and still had to get to a terminal with CTRL-ALT-F6.

Then this bit of GitHub advice: https://gist.github.com/erikvip/0e46a6d9ad742c81d148 seems to have gotten the default video driver working again, with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

And then finally, I got back to a working desktop with advice from here: https://medium.com/@singh.shreya8/how-to-fix-blank-screen-no-icons-after-login-in-ubuntu-14-04-ubuntu-16-04-a5a58ba9a779

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
sudo shutdown -r now
```

These steps have all gotten me back to a working GUI at login.
-- Bob